# How to create a .bed file from .fasta?

Tags: fasta, samtools, bed, bedtools, igv

I have some problems in creating a .bed file for hg19, so I will be able to visualize the .bed file in IGV.

The .fasta file contains rows of this form:

```
>chr1:0-1000
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr1:1000-2000
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr1:2000-3000
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr1:3000-4000
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I tried both with biopython:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open(f1) as in_f, open(f1+'.seq','w') as out_f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_f, 'fasta'):
        out_f.write('{}\t0\t{}\n'.format(record.id, len(record))
```

and awk:

```
samtools faidx file.fasta
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1 FS "0" FS $2}' file.fasta.fai  > file.bed
```

Both ways gave me the same output which IGV couldn't work with:

```
chr1:0-1000 0   1000
chr1:1000-2000  0   1000
chr1:2000-3000  0   1000
chr1:3000-4000  0   1000
chr1:4000-5000  0   1000
chr1:5000-6000  0   1000
chr1:6000-7000  0   1000
chr1:7000-8000  0   1000
```

Now I tried to see what would be a valid .bed file format from [UCSC](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables) and the format looks different. For example:

```
#bin    chrom   chromStart  chromEnd
13  chr1    39845715    39846245
19  chr1    87030756    87031903
22  chr1    111148649   111149175
22  chr1    113246065   113246628
```

1. Why my methods don't output the .bed in the same format?
2. How can I make the awk/biopython methods to output a .bed file that IGV can actually load.

[image]

Comment: As @devon-ryan points out below, both of your BED format examples are incorrect. I think it would be helpful for others if you edited your question to give a correct example. See for example http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat#format1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fun little python script I cooked up for the occasion. It will take a standard fasta file as a command-line argument and turn it into the proper bed format. Using your example fasta:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

inFasta = sys.argv[1] # take fasta as command argument

def fastaParser(fasta):
    headers = []
    with open(fasta) as f:
        header = None
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'): # identifies fasta header line
                headers.append(line[1:-1]) # append all of the line that isnt >
                header = line[1:] # in reset header
    newHeader = (header.replace(':',',') for header in headers) # format to be accepted later
    newnewHeader = (header.replace('-',',') for header in newHeader) # format to accept later
    bedHead = (header.split(',') for header in newnewHeader) # separate by comma from format above
    return bedHead

fastaParsed = fastaParser(inFasta) # run the function

headers = list(fastaParsed) # go from generator to list
bedfile = pd.DataFrame(headers) # create dataframe which will output bedfile

bedfile.to_csv('fastabedfile.bed', sep='\t', index=False, header=None) # output bedfile format
```

to run:

```
[dkennetz@nodecn202  fasta_parser]$python fastaParser.py fakeFasta.fa

[dkennetz@nodecn202  fasta_parser]$more fastabedfile.bed
chr1    0       1000
chr1    1000    2000
chr1    2000    3000
chr1    3000    4000
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the FASTA header contains all the information you want. You can easily generate a proper bed file with Biopython:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse('test.fa', 'fasta'):
    lst = record.id.split(':')
    chr_, (start, end) = lst[0], lst[1].split('-')
    print('\t'.join((chr_, start, end)))
```

Note that native Python code is only marginally longer:

```
with open('test.fa') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            lst = line.rstrip().split(':')
            chr_ = lst[0].lstrip('>')
            start, end = lst[1].split('-')
            print('\t'.join((chr_, start, end)))
```

Both code snippets output bed format:

```
chr1    0   1000
chr1    1000    2000
chr1    2000    3000
chr1    3000    4000
```

Answer (score 3):

The UCSC format you linked to isn't a BED file, your method should never produce it. What you posted as your desired output is also not a BED file. Below is a BED file:

```
chr1    0       1000
chr1    1000    2000
chr1    2000    3000
chr1    3000    4000
```

awk and biopython were producing the appropriate thing already. You just need to zoom in on a region in IGV. Since it's not a bigBed file, IGV won't show everything at all zoom levels.

As a demonstration, below is the BED file from above in IGV:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your headers are **always** of the form `>chrZ:a-b`, where `chrZ` is a chromosome name, `a` is a zero-indexed, half-open start position, and `b` is a zero-indexed, half-open stop position:

```
$ awk '($0 ~ /^>/){ print substr($0,2) }' in.fa | sed 's/[:|-]/\t/g' > out.bed
```

If your headers contain coordinates using a different index, then you can make adjustments to `$1` and `$2` in the `awk` statement to create zero-indexed, half-open coordinates to export to BED, depending on the initial index.

Comment: How do I do it with biopython?

Comment: I would not use Biopython for this. I recommend using standard Unix tools that are fast and flexible. I would not use a hammer to open a jar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a reference genome sequence file (e.g., `reference.fasta`) available. Getting this kind of file is straightforward.

1) Index the reference genome and map your reads or FASTA sequences to it (for example with bowtie2)

```
# index reference genome (should be precomputed)
bowtie2-build reference.fasta reference
# map reads
bowtie2 -x  reference -U file.fasta -S file.sam
# compress SAM to a BAM (binary) file
samtools view -bS file.sam > file.bam
```

2) Create a BED files from the BAM file using `bedtools`

```
# extract BED file
bedtools bamtobed -i file.bam > file.bed
```

Alternatively, for sliding windows you can generate these from a reference sequence provided that you know the length of each chromosome (perhaps there is a way to extract these directly from `reference.fasta`):

```
# length per chromosome
samtools view -H file.bam | grep "SQ" | cut -d":" -f2-3 | sed 's/LN://' > file.chr.txt
```

Create sliding windows (using only the lengths per chromosome)

```
# create sliding windows
bedtools makewindows -g file.chr.txt -w 1000 > windows.bed
```